# How to prevent gmaps4rails from geocoding during migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, gmaps4rails

I'm using:

```
acts_as_gmappable :process_geocoding => true, :check_process => false
```

But when I was doing a migration, I had all kinds of weirdness happening because it was regeocoding everything, and I think google temporarily blocked me for flooding or something.  Is there a way to set :process_geocoding to false temporarily?  I couldn't find mention of it in the docs anywhere, just how to set it initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you proceed your migrations.

The idea to what you desire is to change the `gmaps4rails_options` instance method ([source code here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/lib/gmaps4rails/acts_as_gmappable.rb#L59)).

Either use a `class_eval` or an `instance_eval` to change it on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  What I ended up doing was updating the ActiveRecord field using #update_attribute to avoid callbacks, but this is a better solution.